# Visual Studio - How to use an existing vsproj's project settings as a template for new project?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, visual-studio-templates

There is some software I want to write a plugin for. The software includes some sample plugins. I want to create a new fresh project but I want to use one of the sample plugin vsproj's project settings as a template.

It doesn't seem very clear on how to do this. If I do "New Project From Existing Code" that only imports the cpp, h, etc files into the new project.

Right now the only way I can see to copy a sample projects settings is to open two instances of VS2005 next to each other and simply mimic the settings... Surely there is a built in method of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could copy the project file and remove all the source files from it.

Then add your new source to that.

Doesn't the software provide a template? When I worked on toolkit that allowed developers to write their own plugins we provided these.

Comment: no template provided for some reasons. How do I create my own template? Is VS2005, Export Template is grayed out...

Comment: @Jakobud - It's a long time since I had to do this and it was back on VC++ 6.0 so my knowledge is *very* rusty and long out of date.